# post on friends wall, graph api IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I searched a lot over the web but I didn't fine a working way to post on friends wall over the graph api.

I want to post message on friends wall through the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first time get friend get friend list

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

then select friend and post his/her wall

```
 [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"frined_ID/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: now I figuered out that I didn't add the permission to post on friends wall, now it works thanks

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that you have the `publish_stream` permission enabled. Here are the other permissions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms